# Why is my function (in my model) output-ing plain text to my view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am a ruby newbie.

I am currently writing a function in my model, that is called from my view.  The goal is to output some simple text with a couple of traditional line breaks 
 that...actually break the line on the webpage.

Only... when I actually call the function the 
 tags are actually written as plain text instead of a line break.  What am I doing wrong?

in my model:

```
   def myfunction
    return "Top line: <br />second line <br />"
   end
```

in my view:

```
<%= @myData.myFunction %>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try <%= @myData.myFunction.html_safe %>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails will automatically escape all output by default - this goes a long way to preventing things like [cross-site scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) attacks.

If you *know* that the code you want to output is safe, you can call `html_safe` on it, ie. `@myData.myFunction.html_safe`.

In an ideal world, your model wouldn't be outputting HTML anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Ah got it.

The problem was that the text being returned is naturally escaped by ruby on rails.

So the solution was to add `.html_safe` on the end of the string that I was returning.

```
<%= @myData.myFunction.html_safe %>
```